# Start an Android Application on Emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am new to developing Android Application and developing a HelloWorld app.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Hello World");
        setContentView(text);

    }
```

But when I run my app on AVD, Following comes in my Console.

```
[2013-04-07 17:01:31 - Myapp] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
[2013-04-07 17:01:48 - Myapp] ------------------------------
[2013-04-07 17:01:48 - Myapp] Android Launch!
[2013-04-07 17:01:48 - Myapp] adb is running normally.
[2013-04-07 17:01:50 - Myapp] Performing com.example.myapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-04-07 17:01:53 - Myapp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'dv'
[2013-04-07 17:01:53 - Myapp] Uploading Myapp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-04-07 17:01:54 - Myapp] Installing Myapp.apk...
[2013-04-07 17:02:05 - Myapp] Success!
[2013-04-07 17:02:05 - Myapp] Starting activity com.example.myapp.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
```

Emulator also starts. But it does not print HelloWorld.

[image]

How i can make my app run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the emulator some time (about 10 minutes). It takes him a very long time to boot up. If you wait long en ought then the android logo will disappear and you will receive the home screen.

You can take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to speed-up the emulator:

[Speed UP the Emulator](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527)

Comment: It has been 10 minutes but it is not starting. :(

Comment: just give it time, it will boot up eventually.

Comment: Is it a one time thing or it wil happen everytime I change some code and run it on Emulator.

Comment: no this happens only when you boot your emulator after starting your computer, usually I don't close it after booting it up. you can check my edit of the question with a way to speed up the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The android emulator can take a while to load up. Sometimes it can take three or four minutes before I see the android home screen